# Parsing lines of variables to files in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

Let's say I have a file containing an arbitrary number of variables that can be set to either numbers or strings (strings do not include `;` or `=` or whitespace). Variables are separated by semicolons (whitespace doesn't matter) and each line contains a different set of variables.

```
A = 1; B = ball
A = 2; B = ball; C = C3
```

I want to parse this file in such a way that it writes one file like so:

```
A=1
B=ball
```

and another file like so:

```
A=2
B=ball
C=C3
```

How can this be accomplished in Bash?

Comment: The strings that I am parsing do not include ; or = or whitespace. Yes, it must be bash.

Comment: Yes, it has been edited. I am writing in a terminal (although I admittedly do not know enough of the distinctions between Bash and other shells- if there is another language accessible from the terminal that can accomplish this in an easier manner, then that would also work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use awk:

```
awk -F ';' '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i>NR}' file
```

- `-F ';'`: Sets the field separator to semicolon;
- `gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"")`: Removes all blanks;
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i>NR`: Each line will be associated to a file. Line 1 to file 1, line 2 to file 2, etc. Each variable-value pair will be printed on a line of the corresponding file.

Results will be files `1` and `2`:

```
$ cat 1
A=1
B=ball
$ cat 2
A=2
B=ball
C=C3
```